# Non-parametric correlation for continuous and dichotomous variables

Tags: correlation, categorical-data, nonparametric, heteroscedasticity

I have two variables I want to test with correlation, one is continuous and the other dichotomous. My data are non-normally distributed, plus the variance is heterogeneous, so I have to apply a non-parametric test of correlation. The problem is, I don't know of any test that fits my requirements.

Spearman's correlation coefficient requires ordinal data for both variables.

Point-biserial correlation coefficient fits my data type, but it's a parametric test.

I'm unaware if there's some test else out there. What should I do?

Comment: Why do you need a *correlation*? Why not just run a Mann-Whitney U-test? (Btw, Spearman's correlation is fine if 1 variable is dichotomous.)

Comment: I need a correlation because the groups are not independent, Mann-Whitney U-test requires independent groups if I'm right. If you tell me that Spearman is fine with a categorical dichotomy, I should kill myself for spending so much time looking for alternatives xD

Comment: In what sense are your data not independent? If eg these were pre & post measurements of the same study units, you could use a Wilcoxon signed rank test. There is no meaningful ordinal - nominal difference if there are just 2 categories; if you had 3+ nominal categories, you could not use the Spearman correlation.

Comment: A brief explanation of how location tests for one binary variable relate to correlation is here: [Correlations between continuous and categorical (nominal) variables](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/102778/correlations-between-continuous-and-categorical-nominal-variables). [If you properly account  for the effect of the heavy ties on the distribution a correlation might be okay.]

Answer (score 1):

Consider Rank Biserial Correlation.

"A formula is developed for the correlation between a ranking (possibly including ties) and a dichotomy, with limits which are always ±1. This formula is shown to be equivalent both to Kendall'sτ and Spearman's ρ"

Reference: E. E. Cureton (1956) "Rank Biserial Correlation", Psychometrika, 21, pp. 287-290.

Comment: As this method amounts to at most a reformulation of previously existing methods, it has few followers so far as I can tell.