# How to find correlation between continuous variable and yes/no question?

Tags: correlation

I'm trying to find out if there is correlation between website clicks and sales. In order to do this, I'm trying to find the correlation between a nominal question (Yes and No) and a continuous variable (Total Sales). I recoded the variables to 0 and 1, but I'm not sure what the best method is for determining correlation between the two.

This is what my data originally looked like:

```
Website Visit     Sales
Yes               20.99
Yes               9.99
No                0.00
No                7.99
Yes               12.99
No                0.00
Yes               0.00
```

This is what my data looks like after recoding the variables:

```
Website Visit     Sales
1                 1
1                 1
0                 0
0                 1
1                 1
0                 0
1                 0
```

Essentially, what I've done is **1** if the website was visited and **0** if the website was not visited. Then, **1** if there was a sale and **0** is there was not a sale.

How can I determine if these two variables are correlated or not?

Thank you!

Comment: Try logistic regression, or some variant where you spline the continuous variable ... see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/102778/correlations-between-continuous-and-categorical-nominal-variables, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/140710/correlation-between-continuous-and-binary-variables/372731#372731,  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/194525/correlation-between-quantitative-crime-rates-and-yes-no-variables/413142#413142,