# Binary and Continuous Correlation

Tags: correlation, excel

I'm confused about finding correlation in these two cases with using Excel:
1- Correlation of two binary variables : (Male/Female,Interest to Coffee(Yes/NO))
2- Correlation between one continuous and one binary : (Age,Interest to Coffee (Yes/NO))

Would you tell me or show me clear example since i'm beginner in statistics. I use Excel.

Comment: I think you can use this formula to calculate by hand $r = r_{xy} =\frac{\sum ^n _{i=1}(x_i - \bar{x})(y_i - \bar{y})}{\sqrt{\sum ^n _{i=1}(x_i - \bar{x})^2} \sqrt{\sum ^n _{i=1}(y_i - \bar{y})^2}}$ Also read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient

Comment: Note that for binary variables the correlation bounds can be ver different from +1 or -1.

Answer (score 2):

**Correlation of two binary variables**
You might want to look at the phi coefficient. It is a measure of association between two binary variables.
The formula and the details are better explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phi_coefficient)

**Correlation between one continuous and one binary**
You might want to check @kjetil b halvorsen's answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/102778/correlations-between-continuous-and-categorical-nominal-variables), about the fallacies of using Spearman coefficient and also discusses a nice alternative approach.

Comment: thanks, but both of them are confusing for me! is there any simple example available for both calculations? I couldn't understand these procedures!

Comment: Okay, I understand.

It would be better if you look at the Pearson Correlation Coefficient (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient)

This is a very common method for calculating association between two variables. This (https://support.office.com/en-za/article/PEARSON-function-0c3e30fc-e5af-49c4-808a-3ef66e034c18) might help you in implementing it in Excel. 

And, for understanding the Spearman measure, you can refer to (http://www.real-statistics.com/correlation/spearmans-rank-correlation/).

After understanding it, you would understand kjetil's answer too