# Correlation between a continuous and multinomial variable

Tags: correlation, anova, categorical-data, continuous-data

I would like to find the correlation between a continuous (dependent variable) and a categorical (multinomial) variable. I found that the appropriate test is Eta ($\eta$) coefficient, however, I haven't found enough resources support this test.

Is this the right test ?

Comment: See   https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/102778/correlations-between-continuous-and-categorical-nominal-variables

Comment: I assume your approach with Eta would be to run a one-way analysis of variance, calculate eta-squared from that analysis, and then take the square root of eta-squared... (?)

Comment: Jacob Cohen, 1988, Statistical Power Analysis for the Behavioral Sciences, 2nd, discusses the use of Eta and Eta-squared as effect size statistics in the case of analysis of variance.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you do a 
[one-way analysis of variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_analysis_of_variance).

The aim will be to compare the means of each group determined by the categorical variable. I.e., the null hypothesis will be:
$$
H_0: \mu_a = \mu_b = \mu_c = \ldots
$$