# Finding an association between two methods of medical intervention and a continuous variable

Tags: r, binary-data, continuous-data, association-measure

I have here with me, two methods of intervention; a standard care method, and a specialised intervention. Different individuals receive different method, its all randomly allocated. I am trying to find the association of the specialised intervention and a 'well being score' which is a numerical value. What is the best way to find any associations? E.g. logistic regression model?

Comment: Would you consider the well being score to be continuous or ordinal ?

Comment: it is indeed, continuous.

Comment: Probably the most common method as a measure of association between a dichotomous variable and a continuous variable is point biserial correlation.  It is my understanding that this is the same as Pearson correlation where you use the dichotomous variable as one of the variables.  A significance test can be performed for this correlation as well.

Comment: For association measure, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/102778/correlations-between-continuous-and-categorical-nominal-variables   but logistic regression could also be useful.