# Corelation between 2 level categorical variables and a continuous variable

Tags: machine-learning, python

I have a dataset where I need to find the relation between the smoking habits  of a person (Yes/No) with the probability risk of a person getting a heart disease.

Please suggest how can I find the correlation between 2 level categorical feature( smoking) to continuous variable(Risk) in Python. Can Pearson correlation coefficient be used ?

Comment: maybe check this ? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/102778/correlations-between-continuous-and-categorical-nominal-variables/102800#102800

Answer (score 0):

You could perform logistic regression:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression
The absolute value of the correlation coefficient will roughly tell you how useful your continuous variable is for predicting the yes/no variable. If the slope is zero, is has no predictive power.