# How to determine relationship categorical and numerical data

Tags: r, regression, time-series, correlation, categorical-data

I have two data frames and I would like to determine correlation or another type of relationship between them.

The first data frame is consumption of soft drinks weekly (in liters).

```
Soft drinks consumption

ID  WEEK1   WEEK2   WEEK3 ......  WEEK 28
1   1.8     2       2.5   ......  5
2   0.7     0.3     0.5   ......  1
.
.
.
1108 1      2       3    ......   1
```

So I have liters of soft drinks consumed on sample of 1108 people.

Than I have data frame that shows that a same person had an infection in actual week.(1 is infection, 0 no infection)

```
Infection
ID  WEEK1   WEEK2   WEEK3 ......  WEEK 28
1   1       0       0     ......  1
2   0       0       0     ......  0
.
.
.
1108 1      0       0    ......   0
```

Could you suggest me some method, test or type of linear regression, which I could use to determine relationship between consumption of soft drinks and infections?

I would like to use R software, so if you could suggest and methodology I would very appreciate that.

Comment: This looks like a time series problem. What you could try is to predict infection/no infection using a logistic regression and t-1, t-2, t-3, etc drinks consumption as features.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/102778/correlations-between-continuous-and-categorical-nominal-variables

Answer (score 2):

You could build what is known as a classifier. Predict 'Infection' from 'Consumption'.

In statistics, we use a capital letter $P$ for probability, as your prior. For probability densities a small letter $p$ is used. Bayes rule is what you should basically compute:

$
\begin{split}
P(Infec \mid Cons) =&
&\frac{p(Cons \mid Infec) P(Infec)}{p(Cons \mid Infec) P(Infec) + p(Cons \mid \neg Infec) P(\neg Infec)}
\end{split}
$

Here, the density $p(Cons \mid Infec)$ can be the normal distribution of Comsumption for the infected cases, the density $p(Cons \mid \neg Infec)$ can be the normal distribution of Comsumption for the cases without infection. The terms $P(Infec)$ and $P(\neg Infec)$ are the prior probabilities of being infected, or not.

The densities may be normally distributed, or follow a different continuous distribution. You can perform a discriminant analysis in the software R, in order to make these calculations. The better the predictions (the accuracy) the stronger the relationship between your two variables.