# Show correlation with yes and no answers

Tags: correlation

I am looking to see a correlation between domestic violence and violent crime. It is a yes and no dataset. What will be the best way to show correlation?

total no 53
no with violent crime 38
no with domestic violence 25
no with dc and vc 18

this is the data I have if that helps?

Comment: have a look into logistic regression or point-biserial correlation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correlations between continuous and categorical (nominal) variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/102778/correlations-between-continuous-and-categorical-nominal-variables)

Comment: *"total no 53 no with violent crime 38 no with domestic violence 25 no with dc and vc 18"* Could you please rephrase that? Maybe add punctuation or, better, show it as a table?